# How to autocollapse featuregrid table (OpenGeo Suite SDK Client)

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk

I was working on the OpenGeo Suite tutorials to develop web applications using Geoexplorer. When I launched Geoexplorer from dashboard, I could see readily available 'query' tool embeded there along with other tools. When I click query tool, I can see a collapsible table at the bottom along with  with query tool. Here is the screenshot,

[image]

Fifure: 1

Now I followed the tutorials to build complete application using SDK client. Tutorials say about making a 'Featuregrid' which is not collapsible as shown in the upper image (Figure : 1). Also they did not include query tool using SDK client. I write the following code to add query tool,

`{
  ptype: "gxp_queryform",
  featureManager: "states_manager",
  outputConfig: {
    title: "Query",
    width: 320
  },
  actionTarget: "map.tbar"
}`

Now I can see query tool on ly map toolbar. But if I select this, I don't see any collapsible table, but only the query box. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Figure : 2

My question is , how can I implement a query tool using SDK client that will also output a collapsible table like in Geoexplorer (Figure:1). And can I auto  hide the featuregrid table in Figure 2?

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the source code of GeoExplorer's Composer, that should give you all the hints you need for solving your problem:

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/static/script/app/GeoExplorer/Composer.js